# 'ServiceError' when trying to run Elastic Beanstalk Create from CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

trying to deploy a Django App on AWS using Beanstalk. This is the first time I'm doing this, and for some reason I keep running into this error when I run 'eb create'.

I do have a service role called 'aws-elasticbeanstsalk-service-role' set up, along with these four permission policies:

AWSElasticBeanstalkEnhancedHealth

AdministratorAccess-AWSElasticBeanstalk

AWSElasticBeanstalkService

AWSElasticBeanstalkManagedUpdatesCustomerRolePolicy

Any thoughts on how I can go about fixing there/where I'm going wrong?

Thanks,

```
eb create StudySnap --service-role aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role
```

```
WARNING: Insufficient IAM privileges. Unable to determine if instance profile 'aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role' exists, assuming that it exists.
Creating application version archive "app-389d-230802_143632812825".
Uploading study-snap-ebs-cli/app-389d-230802_143632812825.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
Environment details for: StudySnap
  Application name: study-snap-ebs-cli
  Region: us-east-1
  Deployed Version: app-389d-230802_143632812825
  Environment ID: e-ucqmzyttii
  Platform: arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-east-1::platform/Python 3.11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2023/4.0.2
  Tier: WebServer-Standard-1.0
  CNAME: UNKNOWN
  Updated: 2023-08-02 18:36:36.883000+00:00
Printing Status:
2023-08-02 18:36:35    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2023-08-02 18:36:37    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-170343172677 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2023-08-02 18:36:39    ERROR   Unable to assign role. Please verify that you have permission to pass this role: aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role.
2023-08-02 18:36:39    ERROR   Failed to launch environment.
```